# Error installing Sharepoint Foundation 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, installation

I have installed SharePoint Foundation 2013 on a Windows 2019 Server. With some help from the internet I managed that.

When I start the configuration wizard I get the following error in stage 3:

> "Eine Ausnahme vom Typ 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException' wurde ausgelöst. Weitere Ausnahmeinformationen: Es gibt keine Datei mit URL "_catalogs/masterpage/minimal.master" in dieser Website.
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Es gibt keine Datei mit URL "_catalogs/masterpage/minimal.master" in dieser Website"

English meaning is:

> An exception occured - a file with the url "_catalogs/masterpage/minimal.master" cannot be found.

Has anyone a guess about that?

With kind regards,
Markus

Comment: is there anything interesting in the ULS logs?

Comment: No, i get the error while installing SharePoint. It happens when the configuration wizard tries to create the central administration.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 supports up to Windows Server 2012 R2 when using the SharePoint 2013 *with* Service Pack 1 installer (note you cannot create a slipstream yourself). In addition, SharePoint 2013 supports a maximum of SQL Server 2014.

[Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-0#software-requirements)

There are API changes in various components on Windows Server 2019, IIS in particular, that will make installing SharePoint 2013 on Windows Server 2019 impossible. The only version of SharePoint compatible with Windows Server 2019 is SharePoint Server 2019.